# PHP: Extracting numbers from a page

Tags: php, regex, matching

Im extracting data from a page with multiple userinput ratings, which means the syntax is a bit sloppy.
The text goes something like this:

```
<span date="12/10/2014">4.957/10</span>
<span date="12/10/2014">11/10</span>
<span date="12/10/2014">5 / 10</span>
<span date="12/10/2014">i say: 9 /10</span>
<span date="12/10/2014">10/ 10</span>
<span date="12/10/2014">0.1/10, no more</span>
```

how would you go about fetching these ratings?
the ratings will go from 0 to 1000000, and have a maximum of 3 decimals.

The resulting array of the above should be:

```
4.957
11
5
9
10
0.1
```

So basically the rules should go like this:
* Match any number with "/10" behind it.
* The number can be followed by a dot and up to 3 additional numbers.
* There might be a space between the / and the rating, also between the / and 10.
* There should not be another / after the /10.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also do you have the data from code box 1 saved in a variable?

Comment: Do you definitely need to process it with PHP?

Comment: yes it needs to be in PHP

Comment: this is what i have so far `$sick_number_regex = '\b(?<![\d\.-])\d(\.\d)?(?!(\.\d)|\d)\b|\b(?<![\d\.-])10(?!(\.\d)|\d])\b';` however this only goes from 0.0 to 10.0

Comment: rizier: yes the data there is saved into a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd just grab the number, and then outside of the regex work out if it fits within your bounds:

```
'(\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?)\s*/\s*10(?![^<]*/)'
```

#### Update

I realized mine failed when there were more than three decimal positions (grabbed the wrong number), so here's a better one:

```
'(?<![\d.])(\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?)\s*/\s*10(?![^<]*/)'
```

Comment: Note that I assume you still have the HTML in the string you're matching, if not then replace `[^<]` with just `.`

Answer (score -1):

Try this regular expression:

```
[\d]+\.?[\d]*|[\d]*\.?[\d]+
```

What it actually does is to match the first occurrence of a number in a string that will look like 10 or 0.10 or .10 or 10. (the number parts could contain any digit).

For a better explanation of what it does see: https://www.regex101.com/

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you had that number already in a variable, that's what I understand from the previous comments

Comment: In that case I would split the problems to two simpler ones. Use a regex to get contents inside the <span> tag and then extract the number.

Comment: @KristianRafteseth This could work as well: .*>[^\d]*([\d]+\.?[\d]*|[\d]*\.?[\d]+)[^\d]*.*<.*